# Django и маршрутизация без указания явного url?

Tags: python, django

Планируется построить мини CMS на Django. Планируется, что у пользователя будет иметься возможность задавать url материалов/групп-материалов через админку.

Имеется ли возможность не указывать явный url в маршрутизаторе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, это возможно.

**1 Способ:** используя регулярные выражения в *urls.py* вашего приложения.

**Пример:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^articles/2003/$', views.special_case_2003),
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/$', views.year_archive),
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/$', views.month_archive),
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]+)/$', views.article_detail),
]
```

> Актуально для версии Django <2.0

**2 Способ:** указывая формат и имя переменной в *urls.py* вашего приложения.

**Пример:**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import WearShopClass, WearShopCatClass, WearShopObjClass

urlpatterns = [
    path('', WearShopClass.as_view(), name='wear-main'),
    path('<slug:cat>/', WearShopCatClass.as_view(), name='wear-cat'),
    path('<slug:cat>/<int:id>/', WearShopObjClass.as_view(), name='wear-prod1'),
    path('<slug:cat>/<slug:slug>/', WearShopObjClass.as_view(), name='wear-prod2'),
]
```

> Актуально для версии Django 2.0+

**Дополнение:** Если же в Django версии 2.0+ вам необходимо использовать регулярные выражения, то достаточно импортировать `re_path`.

```
from django.urls import include, re_path

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^index/$', views.index, name='index'),
    re_path(r'^bio/(?P<username>\w+)/$', views.bio, name='bio'),
    re_path(r'^weblog/', include('blog.urls')),
    ...
]
```